# Sample size - Before/After Study - percentage variation

Tags: sample-size

I need to calculate the sample size required for a Before/After Study with an Intervention group and a placebo group (ratio 2:1).
The variables are continuous and are supposed to be normally distribuited.
We need to be able to detect with 0.8 power and 0.05 alpha a percentage variation of +/-20% in the intervention or placebo group.
Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Comment: You don't have enough information: you need to make assumptions about the mean placebo group value and about the variances within both groups.

Comment: Thank you whuber! 
The baseline values in both groups will be considered to be equal (it is a randomized trial) and will be supposed to be, on the base of previous studies, 2000+/-800 (mean+-standard deviation). Actually we can suppose no variation in the placebo group, but we would like to detect at least 20% variation in the intervention group. Thank you!

Comment: If there is no variation in the placebo group and variation in the intervention group, then *for that reason alone* the groups are not the same.  This is inconsistent with a randomized trial.  I suspect you misunderstand what I meant by "variance": that is a statistical measure of *spread within a group.*  It is an essential determiner of sample size, because wider spreads make it more difficult to detect differences and therefore require larger samples.